Keycloak does not create tables in PostgreSQL when using Docker Compose
I am trying to set up Keycloak with PostgreSQL using Docker Compose, but the tables are not being created in PostgreSQL, even though the Keycloak application itself runs without any issue.
Despite the application starting correctly and the admin console being accessible, when I check the PostgreSQL database, I don't see any tables created (e.g., REALM, USER_ENTITY, etc.).
When I run Keycloak outside of Docker, by using kc.bat from the Keycloak installation files, the tables are created successfully in the PostgreSQL database.
It seems that Docker is somehow affecting the table creation process, though no major error is logged that would indicate a failure.
I have tried every combination I could think of: using a custom Dockerfile, not using a Dockerfile, changing versions of Keycloak and PostgreSQL, and adjusting environment variables. I've researched extensively, applied several proposed solutions from similar cases, and even tried running Keycloak outside Docker using kc.bat, which successfully creates the tables. However, within Docker, no tables appear despite the lack of errors in logs, and I'm at a loss on how to solve this issue.
Could anyone please help me figure out why the tables aren't being created with Docker? Thank you
Here is the setup I am using:
Dockerfile:
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.6 as builder

ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Construisez la configuration de Keycloak

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

ENV KC_DB=postgres
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead

RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

# Étape finale pour démarrer Keycloak

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.6

# Copier les fichiers de la phase de construction

COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# Définir les variables d'environnement pour la base de données et Keycloak

ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=newkeycloakuser
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
ENV KC_DB_SCHEMA=public

# Utiliser "start-dev" pour rester en mode développement

ENTRYPOINT \["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"\]

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: newkeycloakuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 623006
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

  keycloak:
    build: .
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: newkeycloakuser
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin   # Ajout de KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin  # Ajout de KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  keycloak_network:
    driver: bridge

logs:
2024-10-02 18:43:08.314 UTC [68] ERROR:  relation "migration_model" does not exist at character 25
2024-10-02 18:43:08.314 UTC [68] STATEMENT:  SELECT ID, VERSION FROM MIGRATION_MODEL ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC
2024-10-02 18:43:09.270 UTC [68] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist at character 22
2024-10-02 18:43:09.270 UTC [68] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
2024-10-02 18:43:09.597 UTC [69] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
2024-10-02 18:43:09.597 UTC [69] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock


What commands did you use to check if keycloak-related tables are created in your database or not? The log you shared does not mean table not created. In my experience, keycloak creates tables after running such queries if tables do not exist.
In your keycloak database, can you run \dt and share the result?
